# UWP - UserControl does not display given data correctly

Tags: listview, user-controls, uwp

I have a UWP app which in a page of it I display a List of items. Those items are not all of the same class, however, there are many properties which are the same between those classes. Because of this, I prefer to use one UserControl over having multiple UserControl and using TemplateSelector. But data won't display as I expect.

Here I give you an example of it.

I have a class named **Base**:

```
public class Base
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and 2 classes which derive from it:

```
public interface ILiker
{
    int LikeCount { get; set; }
    bool? IsLiked { get; set; }
}

public class Liker : Base, ILiker
{
    public int LikeCount { get; set; }
    public bool? IsLiked { get; set; }
}

public interface IFollower
{
    int FollowCount { get; set; }
    bool? IsFollowed { get; set; }
}

public class Follower : Base, IFollower
{
    public int FollowCount { get; set; }
    public bool? IsFollowed { get; set; }
}
```

My list items are of type **Liker** or **Follower** and because of this I've implemented another class to unify them:

```
public class Unified
{
    private Type _type;

    public Unified(Follower item)
    {
        _type = item.GetType();
        BaseInfo = (Base)item;
        FollowerInfo = (IFollower)item;
    }

    public Unified(Liker item)
    {
        _type = item.GetType();
        BaseInfo = (Base)item;
        LikerInfo = (ILiker)item;
    }

    public Base BaseInfo { get; set; }
    public ILiker LikerInfo { get; set; }
    public IFollower FollowerInfo { get; set; }

    public new Type GetType()
    {
        return _type;
    }
}
```

Sometimes I need to display **Base** class in 2 different places inside one list item, because of that I created a separate **BaseTemplate**:

**BaseTemplate.xaml**:

```
<UserControl ...>
    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <TextBlock FontSize="15" Foreground="Black" Text="{x:Bind Data.Name}" />
        <TextBlock FontSize="10" Foreground="Gray" Text="{x:Bind Data.Id}" Margin="5" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

**BaseTemplate.xaml.cs**:

```
public sealed partial class BaseTemplate : UserControl
{
    public Base Data
    {
        get { return (Base)GetValue(DataProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Data.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Data", typeof(Base), typeof(BaseTemplate), new PropertyMetadata(null));


    public BaseTemplate()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

and also created a template for my list items:

**UnifiedTemplate.xaml**:

```
<UserControl ...>
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" Padding="{x:Bind Padding}" BorderBrush="{x:Bind BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{x:Bind BorderThickness}" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <local:BaseTemplate Data="{x:Bind Data.BaseInfo}" />

        <Button
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Content="{x:Bind Data.BaseInfo}">
            <Button.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <local:BaseTemplate Data="{Binding}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </Button.ContentTemplate>
        </Button>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Background="SlateGray">

            <RichTextBlock x:Name="LikeBlock" x:DeferLoadStrategy="Lazy">
                <Paragraph>
                    <InlineUIContainer>
                        <TextBlock Text="Like Count: " />
                    </InlineUIContainer>
                    <Run Text="{x:Bind Data.LikerInfo.LikeCount}" />
                    <LineBreak />
                    <InlineUIContainer>
                        <ToggleButton Content="Like" Tapped="OnLikeTapped" IsChecked="{x:Bind Data.LikerInfo.IsLiked}" />
                    </InlineUIContainer>
                </Paragraph>
            </RichTextBlock>

            <RichTextBlock x:Name="FollowBlock" x:DeferLoadStrategy="Lazy">
                <Paragraph>
                    <InlineUIContainer>
                        <TextBlock Text="Follow Count: " />
                    </InlineUIContainer>
                    <Run Text="{x:Bind Data.FollowerInfo.FollowCount}" />
                    <LineBreak />
                    <InlineUIContainer>
                        <ToggleButton Content="Follow" Tapped="OnFollowTapped" IsChecked="{x:Bind Data.FollowerInfo.IsFollowed}" />
                    </InlineUIContainer>
                </Paragraph>
            </RichTextBlock>

        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**UnifiedTemplate.xaml.cs**:

```
public sealed partial class UnifiedTemplate : UserControl
{
    public Unified Data
    {
        get { return (Unified)GetValue(DataProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Data.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Data", typeof(Unified), typeof(UnifiedTemplate), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnChanged));

    private static void OnChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var that = d as UnifiedTemplate;

        if (that == null || e.NewValue == null) return;

        var data = (Unified) e.NewValue;

        if (data.GetType() == typeof(Liker))
        {
            that.FindName(nameof(LikeBlock));
        }
        else
        {
            that.FindName(nameof(FollowBlock));
        }
    }


    public UnifiedTemplate()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void OnLikeTapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e) {...}
    private void OnFollowTapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e) {...}
}
```

When I run the app Base class data won't be displayed at all. What's wrong with my approach?
Sorry for this long question, it was the simplest example I could give.

**Edit**: [Here](https://github.com/TheSETJ/UserControl) is a very similar project that reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you give all the code that I can run.

Comment: Had a glance n noticed you are using `x:Bind` without `OneWay` binding. You need to specify the `Mode` to be `OneWay` at least.

Comment: @JustinXL If I do so, there is no point using `x:Bind` anymore, I can use `Binding` instead which does the same thing? As I learned so far, `OneWay` is good for that kind of data that will change and UI will need to be updated based on changes. Am I wrong?

Comment: Nah you got it wrong. The default mode of `x:Bind` is `OneTime`. When the data changes, if you want the UI to reflect the change, use `OneWay` binding.

Comment: @JustinXL I said the exact thing you said. Probably I could not state it very well. Sorry.

Comment: @lindexi It's changed a bit, but it still doesn't show data correctly. Here: https://github.com/TheSETJ/UserControl

Comment: lol, OK, you said there's no point using `x:Bind`, that bit is not right. `x:Bind` gives you performance boost, and if you need to notify the UI, you need to do something like `{x:Bind Property1, Mode=OneWay}`.